# How to change filename alongwith ext in C/CPP

Tags: c++, c

I have hundreds of files in a folder like:

```
mp_12345.dat
mp_23455.dat
mp_12323.dat
mp_44445.dat
.
.
.
```

I want to rename all file to another folder:

```
Ind_somecircle_mp_12345.mbin
Ind_somecircle_mp_23455.mbin
Ind_somecircle_mp_12323.mbin
Ind_somecircle_mp_44445.mbin
.
.
```

And so on.

source folder: `/home/dir1/foo/`
destination folder: `/home/dir2/foo/`
I am looking for C or C++ code to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in C or C++?

Comment: Sounds like a job for bash or python.

Comment: consider to use `boost-filesystem` it not quite lightweight but crossplatform.

Comment: The last time I had to do such a thing, I used Python. I would suggest you to do the same, unless you are doing this for some academic/learning purpose.

Answer (score 7):

Actually this would be a better job for a shell script, but if you insist on C then `rename(src, tgt);` is what you are looking for.

If you want to read the filenames from the directory, you must use `opendir` and `readdir` to loop through the files.

A short sample:

```
void main(int c,char **args)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dent;
    dir = opendir("mydir);
    if(dir!=NULL)
    {
        while((dent=readdir(dir))!=NULL)
            printf(dent->d_name);   <-- rename
    }
    close(dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using C/C++ for the job you need to use

opendir - http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir, readdir - http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir to get the list of files

That use rename - http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename to change the filename of a file